# configuring visual studio 2012 & team foundation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I just started working in `Visual Studio 2012` in a project group. We are using `team foundation server` to share our code. I have a couple of problems here I was hoping someone could help me solve them.

1. I have succesfully connected to our TFS-server and checked out the project, but for some reason when I check my solution explorer it says "0 solutions". I dont know if this is a problem but I feel like it has something to do with my other problems.
2. I can't, for some reason, press the `play` button to start debug, also in the menu the debug option is greyed out, 5 obv doesent work either. And in the "project" tab I dont have the option to set my project as startup project wich would make it so that I can debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Source Control Explorer. There you can navigate the code in TFS. Make sure there are files checked in to this location. If not, you will first have to add your project to TFS.

If there are files in TFS, map the files to a location on your harddrive. Then open the solution file by double clicking it in your Solution Explorer.

The MSDN has a nice walktrough: [Set Up Team Foundation Server for Version Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301771.aspx)

Comment: I do have all files in my Source control explorer, and they are maped to a location as well, I can even edit the code, check in new code and w/e, I just cant debug it for some reason, and that means that I cant view the webpage in chrome/firefox and that kinda makes it impossible to work with the css for example..

Comment: You don't see any files in your solution explorer? Do you open them trough Explorer?

Comment: In the solution explorer tab it sais "Solution 'solution 1' (0 projects)".. And what do you mean by open them through Explorer??

Comment: How do you edit the files if you don't see them in your solution explorer? I would try right clicking your Solution file and then choose 'Add existing project', navigate to your project file and add it.

Comment: I just go to the Team Explorer tab, under "Pending Changes" I hit Source Control Explorer and I find all of our files in the project there, and just to clarify this is my first time working in VS so Im kinda clueless.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the local path has to be in the visual studidio\projects folder... re-mapped it and works as intended. No need to answer this anymore, thanks for your suggestions though :)

Comment: Accept this post as answer so you can mark this question as "Answered"